# Custom template memcmp vs C memcmp

Tags: c++

```
template <typename T>
int custom_memcmp(const T* a, const T* b, std::size_t n);
```

Would this be faster than C's memcmp?

If sizeof(T) != 1: it will perform less iterations and it can compare the values as their actual types. For example I'd except comparing two 'long long's directly to be faster than comparing two 8-byte buffers.

Comment: Why don't you profile it and find out?

Comment: `memcmp` can be implemented as an _intrinsic_ and you can't probably beat that.

Comment: How could we know without seeing the definition? The signature isn't terribly meaningful

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`memcmp` is usually a compiler intrinsic, so will be optimised to be about as efficient as it's possible to get (will be vectorised, inlined, etc.).

So you almost certainly won't beat it.  But of course, if you want to know for sure, then just profile!

Answer (score 2):

No, it won't be faster.  memcmp will just compare the raw memory of appropriate sizes as efficiently as possible.  Only a naive implementation of memcmp would do it byte by byte.